# RETURN comma list with NULLs if item not found IN list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor). We are inputing sensor data into this database at 1Hz. Each test has a variable number of sensors that could be of any type. The channel name (`ChName`) will describe to the user what they are.

The user will select the `TestID` and which `ChName`'s they want from a web interface.

I have a table that is setup like this but contains approximately 15 million rows with ~50 TestIDs:

`Timestamp datetime`, `TestID int`, `ChName varchar(100)`, `Value real`

```
Timestamp | TestID | ChName | Value
13:52:12  | 1000   | A      | 23
13:52:12  | 1000   | B      | 2
13:52:12  | 1000   | C      | 150
13:52:13  | 1000   | A      | 25
13:52:13  | 1000   | C      | 147
13:52:13  | 1000   | B      | 1
13:52:14  | 1000   | A      | 24
13:52:14  | 1000   | B      | 4
13:52:14  | 1000   | C      | 151
13:52:15  | 1000   | B      | 8
13:52:15  | 1000   | C      | 153
13:52:16  | 1000   | B      | 3
13:52:16  | 1000   | C      | 149
13:52:17  | 1000   | C      | 152
13:52:17  | 1000   | A      | 27
```

I am looking for a query that when searching for a specific `TestID` and specific `ChName`'s it will return a comma separated result in the order searched with NULLs for those not found.

For example searching for `TestID` 1000 and `ChNames` ('A','B','C') would return:

```
Timestamp  | Data
13:52:12   | 23,2,150
13:52:13   | 25,1,147
13:52:14   | 24,4,151
13:52:15   | NULL,8,153
13:52:16   | NULL,3,149
13:52:17   | 27,NULL,152
```

Searching for `TestID` 1000 and `ChNames` ('B','C') would return:

```
Timestamp  | Data
13:52:12   | 2,150
13:52:13   | 1,147
13:52:14   | 4,151
13:52:15   | 8,153
13:52:16   | 3,149
13:52:17   | NULL,152
```

I've implemented this in PHP returning all rows that contain the `TestID` and `ChName`'s but it is slow (returning ~503,000 rows and doing the grouping in PHP takes approximately 2 minutes). I do believe the table could be structured better but unfortunately I inherited the design so trying to get a more efficient query.

Purpose of this data is to pull it and export to excel or the user can graph it via a webapp. User has the ability to select all data or a certain time period.

The query when requesting all data looks like this and then in PHP I group them and add the NULL if not found.

```
SELECT Timestamp,ChName,Value FROM data_table WHERE TestID=1000 AND ChName IN ('A','B',C') ORDER BY Timestamp,ChName
```

Comment: is `'A','B','C'` a param?  hard to tell since you didnt include the sql you've tried

Comment: Include your query. Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use `PIVOT` and build the query dynamically based on the list of values for `ChName` you want to produce the result for:

```sql
SELECT TimeStamp, 
       COALESCE([A], 'NULL') + ',' + 
       COALESCE([B], 'NULL') + ',' + 
       COALESCE([C], 'NULL') AS Data
FROM
    (   SELECT TimeStamp, ChName, Value 
        FROM   data_table
        WHERE  TestID = 1000
        AND    ChName IN ('A',B',C')
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
        Max(Value)
        FOR ChName IN ([A], [B], [C])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

I have not tested this, so it may have some syntax issues.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Reduced my loading time by more than half. Thanks. I did refine the 2nd `SELECT` clause to include `AND ChName IN ('A',B',C')`

Comment: Indeed, that additional condition is a good thing. I added it in my answer now as well.